# I can't run the app on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

[image: screenshot[1]]

I finished this project 2 months ago, but when I tried to open it today this is what it gave me. I have no idea what to do next. Could it be from an AS update? Please help

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in this screenshot. What do you mean?

Comment: I think your project is not syncing properly. Try to open your project by selecting gradle file while open project from File Menu.
**File ->  Open -> Select `build.gradle`**. It may solve your problem.

Comment: Try rebuilding your project. It may help.

Comment: Nvm I fixed it, I needed to open the project from the inner folder. Thanks though :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is because the gradle and sdk edition is incompatible, just try to update both to the latest, it may solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do File -> Invalidate cache and Restart.